# Where can I find yum repos for mysql 5.6?

Tags: mysql

OS is SL6. Googling did not turn up any results for a yum repo for mysql 5.6. Percona would also be totally fine, google didn't turn up anything there either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL 5.6 has only just reached GA on February 5](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/1904335). It will take some time (days or perhaps weeks) before any packagers have stable builds available, because changing the MySQL version affects many other system packages.

Comment: Looks like I was jumping the gun a bit! Thanks for the info on that. :)